# Have to press "I" and spacebar to switch to insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim, insert, mode

I have to press "i" and an extra spacebar in order to switch to Insert mode in Vim, which is pretty annoying.

[image: example picture]

You can see there are 5 "i"s on the screen in Normal mode, if I press spacebar, Vim will switch to Normal mode and 4 "i"s will be added to the file.

It has the same problem for "a", "s", "o" and other command key.

Please help.

Comment: You need to provide the .vimrc file in your home directory.

Comment: I had this problem since I installed .vimrc from https://github.com/amix/vimrc. But I uninstall it then reinstall everything and haven't' created another .vimrc file yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the underlining, this looks like a temporary input buffer of an IME (Input Method Editor; to insert non-English characters with a standard keyboard). The application (Vim) doesn't see the characters until you complete the composition (with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key). Only then does Vim receive the characters, and processes them.

You need to turn off the IME, at least for the terminal / Vim. There's usually an icon in the systray where you can select the input method, and often a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> toggles the state of it. Vim can interact with the IME, too, and only use its services for insert mode (to be able to write in Unicode scripts). Read more about it in `:help mbyte-XIM` (Linux) and `:help mbyte-IME` (Windows).

Comment: Thank you sir! This definitely solved my problem. Everything works perfectly when I switched back to the english input method.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.